# Exchange EWS: How to get all appointments in a room

Tags: resources, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get all Appointments of a Room in Exchange via Exchange EWS.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;            
service.AutodiscoverUrl("hans.muster@domain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

// Return all the room lists in the organization. 
EmailAddressCollection roomLists = service.GetRoomLists();

System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<EmailAddress> rooms = service.GetRooms("ZimmerZuerich@domain.com");

EmailAddress roomAdress = rooms[31];

FolderId folderid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(roomAdress.Address));
FindItemsResults<Appointment> aps = service.FindAppointments(folderid, new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24)));
```

If I run this code I get an error message stating:

```
{"The specified folder could not be found in the store."}.
```

And indeed if I show me a collection of all folders for such a room mailbox, there are no folders inside it.

What am I doing wrong? All examples in the internet work with WellKnownFolderName.Calendar.

Answer (score 2):

That error generally indicates your credentials are okay to connect to Exchange but you don't have rights to the calendar you're trying to access so you either need to grant access to the Mailbox using Add-MailboxPermission or Grant Access to the Calendar Folder using Add-MailboxFolderPermissions

Cheers
Glen

Comment: but when I open the Calendar in Outlook with the same credentials, I have no problem accessing it. Do I have to access the mailbox another way round?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the credentials using the service.credentials ? can you use the EWSEditor to access the room mailbox http://ewseditor.codeplex.com/

Comment: Adding permission to the calendar folder solved the issue. For example to allow the user `readonly` to see calendar appointments on `room123`:
`Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity room123@test.example.com:\Calendar -AccessRights Reviewer -User readonly@test.example.com`